# Trying to get filtered response from query with multiple terms from elasticsearch

Tags: json, laravel, elasticsearch, guzzle

As the title states, im trying to make a query that doesnt return the entire document, but only certain fields, but with multiple exact terms.
Im using Guzzle from laravel to contruct my query:

```
            $response = $client->post('cvr-permanent/_search', [
        'auth' => ['USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'],
        'json' => [
            "_source" => ["Vrvirksomhed.attributter", "Vrvirksomhed.deltagerRelation.organisationer.medlemsData.attributter"],
            "query" => [
                "bool"=> [
                    "must"=> [
                        [
                            "term"=> [
                                "Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer" => $vat
                            ]
                        ]],
                    "must_not"=> [ ],
                    "should"=> [ ]
                ]
                            ],
                    "from"=> 0,
                    "size"=> 10,
                    "sort"=> [ ]
        ]
    ]);
```

I want the data from the `Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer` and the data i want is where `Vrvirksomhed.attributter.type => "KAPITAL"` and `Vrvirksomhed.deltagerRelation.deltager.navne` and where `Vrvirksomhed.deltagerRelation.organisation.attributter.type = "EJERANDEL_PROCENT"`

Im very confused about how to make this query work because it is multiple terms but not really. Also very new to elasticsearch.
I tried the "terms" but couldnt really get it to work.
The query i have made above, return way too much data i dont need, and not all the data i DO need.

Hope you can help

**EDIT

Something like this maybe, but translated to elasticsearch
`SELECT attributter.type": "KAPITAL" AND deltagerRelation.deltager.navne AND deltagerRelation.organisation.attributter.type": "EJERANDEL_PROCENT FROM Vrvirksomhed WHERE cvrNummer = $vat`

***EDIT
Hopefully more clarification:

Okay, sorry ill try to make it clearer. The object i want is a company with a certain vat number. So `Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer` is that, and that has to be the term. It returns a gigantic object with so many arrays in arrays. I do not want all of this data but only some of it. The data i need from this big object, is the object in the array `Vrvirksomhed.attributter` that has the `type : "KAPITAL` field, and not all of the attributter. Then i want `Vrvirksomhed.deltagerRelation.deltager.navne` which i can get by just putting it in the `_source` because i want all of these objects. But then i want `Vrvirksomhed. deltagerRelation.organisation.attributter` that again is a bunch of objects in the array `attributter` but i only want the ones with the `type : "EJERANDEL_PROCENT`

So i can´t really add them as additional "terms" because the only real term is the "cvrNummer", everything else is just filtering the response. I tried with filters etc, but to no avail

Heres a pastebin so you can see the clusterfuck i am dealing with. THis is what i have been able to sort it to so far, with putting the things in `_source` but without the extra "filtering" of "KAPITAL" and "EJERANDEL_PROCENT"
https://pastebin.com/b8hWWz1R

Answer (score 1):

You want to get only documents which match several conditions, and you need only a subset of fields from those documents, correct?

In SQL (taking some liberties with the field names and structure), your query would be something like:

```sql
SELECT cvrNummer
FROM Vrvirksomhed
WHERE attributter_type = 'KAPITAL'
  AND deltagerRelation_deltager_navne = 'you left this out in your question'
  AND deltagerRelation_organisation_attributter_type = 'EJERANDEL_PROCENT'
```

As explained in [the Elasticsearch Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html)*†*, the equivalent to this in Elasticsearch is a query with a `bool` [clause](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) that contains all your conditions, and a `_source` [parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-source-filtering.html) which says what fields you want to get back in the response. Something like the following:

```
{
    "_source": ["cvrNummer"]
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "term": "attributter.type": "KAPITAL" },
                { "term": "deltagerRelation.deltager.navne": "you left this out in your question" },
                { "term": "deltagerRelation.organisation.attributter.type": "EJERANDEL_PROCENT" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

*† Do note that the syntax in this guide is for Elasticsearch 2.x. The current version is 7.x, and many things have changed since then!*

- See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html for how to construct a `bool` query using the new syntax;
- see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html for how to use the term-level queries, which you probably want;
- also see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html and consider using filter context, since you probably don't care about the score of your query.

Comment: Very good answer, was helpful about how it works abit more, but i think what im actually looking for is something like `SELECT attributter.type": "KAPITAL" AND deltagerRelation.deltager.navne AND deltagerRelation.organisation.attributter.type": "EJERANDEL_PROCENT
FROM Vrvirksomhed WHERE cvrNummer = $vat` if that makes sense.
The table i Vrvirksomhed and i just need these 3 values from the entry with the chosen cvrNummer

I need every entry in the "navne" field which is why theres no value on it. its a bit of a confusing query tbh

Comment: The answer gives you all the information necessary for you to change the query JSON that I wrote into what you want. (SELECT -> `_source`, WHERE -> `bool`) But if you are willing to pay an hourly consulting fee, I will be glad to write the exact query for you :-)

Comment: That makes no sense, you cannot put conditions in a SELECT clause. Sorry for putting so much weight on the SQL, that is just a tool to try to help understand what you actually want. Your question does not make clear exactly what fields you are trying to retrieve, from which documents. Can you clarify that, maybe by providing a pseudocode example of the result you want? Your previous comment is inconsistent with the sentence in your answer which starts with "I want the data from the `Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer`..."

Comment: Okay sorry, i made another edit to try and make it clearer. Hopefully that helps